# Quick sort working and not-working code comparison

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have two implementations of quick-sort with a small change and I am failing to understand why one of them works and other doesn't.

**Not-working**

```
function quickSort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length){
  console.log(arr,left,right)
  if (left < right){
    let middle = pivot(arr, left, right)
    console.log(middle)
    quickSort(arr, left, middle-1)
    quickSort(arr, middle+1, right)
  }
  return arr
}


function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length)
// returns the correct index
{
 function swap(arr, i, j){
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
  let pivot = arr[start];
  let index = start;
  for (let i = start + 1; i < end; i++){
    if(pivot > arr[i]){
      index++
      swap(arr,i,index)
    }
  }
  swap(arr,index, start)
  return index
}
```

**Working**
The only change here is instead of using the "end" argument, I am using arr.length in the for loop

```
function quickSort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length){
  console.log(arr,left,right)
  if (left < right){
    let middle = pivot(arr, left, right)
    console.log(middle)
    quickSort(arr, left, middle-1)
    quickSort(arr, middle+1, right)
  }
  return arr
}


function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length)
// returns the correct index
{
 function swap(arr, i, j){
    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
  let pivot = arr[start];
  let index = start;
  for (let i = start + 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(pivot > arr[i]){
      index++
      swap(arr,i,index)
    }
  }
  swap(arr,index, start)
  return index
}
```

Both the logics are identical and I am unable to find a difference. Ideally, I would want to reuse the end argument inside my code.
Thanks!

Comment: If end != arr.length (as it would be for any sub-sort not at the end) the second will misbehave by pivoting more than expected

Comment: I see you have taken end = arr.length ..i think it should be arr.length - 1...and in the for loop make < to <= end and you are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing your code, I get that `quickSort(arr, left, right)` will sort the range of `[left, right)`. Means that you are not including `arr[right]` in the sorting algorithm.
So, when you are recursively calling `quickSort(arr, left, middle-1)`, `arr[middle-1]` will not be included ever in your sorting algorithm. So, it doesn't work. You should make it `quickSort(arr, left, middle)`.
However, in your mentioned "working" code, you are always iterating till the last element of the whole array, that's why the case is being handled. But it should never be done that way because it is not contributing anything to improve the complexity.

Comment: Thanks @Sajib!! That helps.